How to limit speed for client in XRay (XTLS)
I have a VPN (3X-UI + XRay) on VPS and I need to distribute Internet speed evenly amoung clients. For example, If the bandwidth is 10 Gbit and I have 100 clients, I can limit the speed of each client to 100 Mbit so they don't get in each other's way. I've decided to pass traffic through NGINX and limit speed. But It doesn't affect the speed at all If I connect through 8888:
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

stream {
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $sni_name {
    hostnames;
    www.google.com xray;
    default xray;
    }

    upstream xray {
        server 127.0.0.1:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 8888;
        proxy_pass $sni_name;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_download_rate 100k;
        proxy_upload_rate 100k;
    }
}

What I'm doing wrong and is it correct way to use reverse proxy for this purpose?

First of all the stream only applies to TCP/UDP connections. If your VPN protocol is based on HTTP it won't limit your speed. Make sure you are using the right protocol or change nginx config accordingly.
You should proxy_pass into your upstream(x-ray) or directly use xray
    server {
        listen 8888;
        proxy_pass xray;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_download_rate 100k;
        proxy_upload_rate 100k;
    }

Also, you have limited the speed to 100k aka 100 Kbps. If you are planning to set it to 100Mbps you should use 100m instead.
